# Exim own log format

Tags: email, smtp, exim

Sorry for my english. Using MTA Exim and I can not understand how you can add logging deliveries (main-logs), another in his field, namely the message id (but not msgid of exim).

Easier to explain with an example. Let us send a letter with account "test".

Files looks like:

```
==> Exim_test_main_20140930.log <==
2014-09-30 13:00:00 1QWERT-QWEASD-QQ <= root@localhost H = [127.0.0.1] P = smtp S = 955 id = 12345@domain
```

Where `1QWERT-QWEASD-QQ` - internal ID exim, and `12345` - msgid of message.

Delivery logging:

```
==> Exim_192.168.0.2_main_20140930.log <==
2014-09-30 13:00:00 1QWERT-QWEASD-QQ => mail@domain R = domain_route T = domain_transport H = mx.domain [213.180.204.89] X = TLS1.2: RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1: 128 C = "250 2.0.0 Ok "DT = 0s [br]
2014-09-30 13:00:00 1XYx27-0004Zf-TF Completed QT = 1s
```

But, I need:

```
2014-09-30 13:00:00 1QWERT-QWEASD-QQ => mail@domain R=domain_route T=domain_transport H=mx.domain.ru [213.180.204.89] X=TLS1.2:RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1:128 C="250 2.0.0 Ok" DT=0s        id=12345@domain
```

A value for the standard config directives exim log_selector provided by ("`+all`" did not help). Please, tell me how I can solve this problem? Probably there is a way through the use of directives acl + warn. But I honestly do not know how done it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not fully described what data you are trying to get from those two lines.  I suspect you want to know the header *Message-Id* and the recipient(s).

The header *Message-Id* is logged on the incoming message log line.  The recipients are logged, one log line per recipient because there can be multiple recipients per inbound mail.  What you need to do is parse the logs and realize that the two lines you quoted above are related due to the Exim Queue ID being the same, and relate the *id=** value from the incoming log line to each of the outgoing log lines.

Without a more detailed statement of what you are trying to do, it's hard to get more specific than this.